# can not inflate text using html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing a form in which click on the image the image would be inflicted and display the comments with the profile picture like facebook. But currently, on my web page, only the image will be displayed, and I want to display other functionality comments and like. How can we add the image along with that likes and comments and also the username?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD9Vv.jpg)
**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
          <div class="gallery">
     <img src="images/1.jpg" id="myImg" >

   <div id="myModal" class="modal">
 <span class="close">&times;</span>
<img class="modal-content"  id="img01">
<div id="caption"></div>
</div>
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
modal.style.display = "block";
modalImg.src = this.src;
captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

 // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
 var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
 span.onclick = function() { 
 modal.style.display = "none";
 } 
 </script>
```

**css**

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */  
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
  }

 /* Modal Content (image) */
 .modal-content {
     margin: auto;
   display: block;
   width: 80%;
   max-width: 700px;
   }

 /* Caption of Modal Image */
  #caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
   width: 80%;
max-width: 700px;
text-align: center;
color: #ccc;
padding: 10px 0;
height: 150px;

 }

  /* Add Animation */
  .modal-content, #caption {    
   -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
   animation-name: zoom;
      animation-duration: 0.6s;
    }

   @-webkit-keyframes zoom {
from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
  }

 @keyframes zoom {
from {transform:scale(0)} 
to {transform:scale(1)}
 }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a working snippet or an image that explains what you mean by inflict?

Comment: I think you want similar to this http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/comment-box.html

Comment: You can refer https://www.script-tutorials.com/facebook-like-photo-gallery-with-comments/ this also

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of what you are trying to do is, Display an image on the left side of a div element and display FB comments on the left with the respective controls to post your own. Is this correct? However, It looks like you may need to incorporate an SQL database for user functions and a comments system.
Do you have any experience as a back-end web-developer? You may want to do some research on MS-SQL/MySQL as well as PHP.

I will do my best to walk you through the process. However, due to the fact that I am a returning hobbyist and haven't dabbled with PHP in 3 years this might be a bit hard to follow.

First and foremost, we need to determine whether your webhost supports such functionality. If you know how to get to your PHPMyAdmin page then chances are your host does allow SQL! If you aren't sure, contact your host's support team.

Now, Lets proceed to the setup. Let us start by creating the database. Navigate to your CPanel and click Create Database. The setup of this database depends completely on your own preference I have found a nice article that explains in detail the process of setting up the PHP script. Hopefully this helps you get a rough idea of how the database needs to be set up. https://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/

If you try to create such systems with native html and javascript, You WILL run into problems that cannot be solved by simple means. At least not securely.

However opposed to this method I may be, If I did not mention it I would be remiss. A less secure option to this is utilization of the display attribute through JavaScript. I.E.

```
var commentpane = document.getElementById('ELEMENT-ID-OF-CONTAINER')
// if pane is showing then hide else show comment pane
if commentpane.style.Display = 'block' then {
    commentpane.style.Display = 'none'
} else {
    commentpane.style.Display = 'block'
)
```

Make sure you have your CSS correctly set up as well. This is a very important step to resolving display issues!

Comment: i have to show static data only there is no need of webhost.